# CAST varchar data type to datetime type using QueryDSL or Spring Data JPA

Tags: datetime, casting, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, varchar

I have a setup of QueryDSL and Spring Data JPA where I'm trying primarily to use **cast** in order to be able to convert a string to a date for comparison and/or order

Below I can do it with **castToNum** provided by QueryDSL itself is there a similar method to do it for a date?

If there is not. Is there any other way I can do it with QueryDSL, Spring Data JPA or a combination?

**Once again my question and what I want to achieve is to cast a varchar column value to datetime for comparison and/or order while querying.**

So something like below

```
where cast(myuser0_.value as datetime)>=?
```

Example of castToNum provided QueryDSL method

```
NumberExpression<Integer> paths = path.castToNum(Integer.class);
    return paths.goe(Integer.parseInt(criteria.getValue().toString()))
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using MySQL database

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTemplate` to define a custom expression that will convert the string value to a date for comparison. Since you're using MySQL you can use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the string value.

```
DateExpression<LocalDate> expression =  Expressions.dateTemplate(LocalDate.class, "STR_TO_DATE({0}, "DD/MON/YYYY")", myuser0_.value);

return expression.goe(compareDate);
```

The date format parameter for `STR_TO_DATE` will be dependent on the format of the date string.